# Parse JSON with Ionic 2 and typescript

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

I'm trying to parse some JSON data from randomuser.me api, to do that a found some tutorials online but aparrently something have change recently in Ionic 2, because none of them are working.

Here is what i have:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  items : any;
  //http://api.randomuser.me/?results=10

  constructor(private navController: NavController, private http: Http) {

    this.http.get("http://api.randomuser.me/?results=10").subscribe(data => {
        console.log("Got data");
        this.items=JSON.parse(data._body).results; // this is the error
        console.log(this.items);
    });
  }

  itemClicked(event, item) {
    console.log(item.title);
    //console.log(event);
  }


}
```

In the terminal i can see the error:
**data._body - Property '_body' is private and only accessible within class 'Response'.**

What can i do?

Answer (score 6):

> data._body for data.text(),

Instead of `data.text()` then parsing it you should use `data.json()`

```
this.items = data.json();
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#extract-data

Answer (score 4):

It has changed in the new versions try this

> `this.items= JSON.parse(data['_body']).results;`

Answer (score 1):

Because Ionic 2 has changed a wee bit I thought I'd share the way I do it.

To access a map function we need to add this line under your import statements

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

then change your constructor to...

```
        this.http.get("http://api.randomuser.me/?results=10").map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        console.log("Got data");
        console.log(this.data);
    });
}
```

Now we can see a JSON string in the console.
Note the only extra bit we added is **.map(res => res.json()**

There is a guy Joshua Morony who does a lot of Ionic 2 videos that you should check out if you are struggling with getting data from an API: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuc4dp0qHSc&index=33&list=PLvLBrJpVwC7ocO1r-xu218C15iE9gTWBA

Comment: how could i show the values to html like {{data.something}}

Comment: This here is the answer as of 15/09/2017. Thanks a lot @rawturtle.